# encrypt and decrypt a string with node

Tags: javascript, node.js, encryption

Im testing this encryption/decryption code found [here](http://lollyrock.com/articles/nodejs-encryption/). The code is:

```
var crypto = require('crypto');

var encrypt = function(text){
    var algorithm = 'aes-256-ctr';
    var password = 'gh6ttr';
    var cipher = crypto.createCipher(algorithm,password)
    var crypted = cipher.update(JSON.stringify(text),'utf8','hex')
    crypted += cipher.final('hex');
    return crypted;
}

var decrypt = function(text){
    var algorithm = 'aes-256-ctr';
    var password = 'gh6ttr';
    var decipher = crypto.createDecipher(algorithm,password)
    var dec = decipher.update(JSON.stringify(text),'hex','utf8')
    dec += decipher.final('utf8');
    return dec;
}

var encrypted = encrypt('test');
console.log('encrypted is ', encrypted);

var decrypted = decrypt(encrypted);
console.log('decrypted is ', decrypted);
```

The results are:

```
encrypted is  66b1f8423a42
decrypted is
```

decrypted is always blank. Any idea why this code doesn't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you use JSON.stringify on an encrypted string...

```
var decrypt = function(text){
    var algorithm = 'aes-256-ctr';
    var password = 'gh6ttr';
    var decipher = crypto.createDecipher(algorithm,password)
    var dec = decipher.update(text,'hex','utf8')
    dec += decipher.final('utf8');
    return JSON.decode(dec);
}
```

EDIT: I need to note that since your question is "encrypt and decrypt a **string** with node" there is absolutely no reason to use the JSON functions in those two functions.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't JSON-stringify the encrypted text when decrypting:

```
var dec = decipher.update(text, 'hex', 'utf8')
```

Answer (score 0):

Have look at the code below :

> **Encrypt the text 'abc'**

```
var mykey = crypto.createCipher('aes-128-cbc', 'mypassword');
var mystr = mykey.update('abc', 'utf8', 'hex')
mystr += mykey.update.final('hex');

console.log(mystr); //34feb914c099df25794bf9ccb85bea72
```

> **Decrypt back to 'abc'**

```
var mykey = crypto.createDecipher('aes-128-cbc', 'mypassword');
var mystr = mykey.update('34feb914c099df25794bf9ccb85bea72', 'hex', 'utf8')
mystr += mykey.update.final('utf8');

console.log(mystr); //abc
```

Hope that helps,

**Good Luck, Cheers**

Ashish Sebastian